# how to show whether an item in the listview is positive or negative inside toast message based on the words initialized in an array of strings?

Tags: android, listview, twitter

I have written a program to get tweets from twitter in a listview , which is working perfectly fine ,i have also initialized an array of positive and negative strings with some words based on which i want to show a positive or negative toast message on each tweet click, need some guidance on how to do it .

```
public class TwitterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, 
ArrayList<TwitterTweet>> {
ListActivity callerActivity;
String[] positive = { "good", "very good", "best", "awesome", "amazing", 
"worth", "fantastic", "impeccable",
        "great", "brilliant", "impressed", "impressive" };

String[] negative = { "bad", "very bad", "worst", "pathetic", "boring", "not  
worth", "not great", "sick",
        "terrible" };

ListView lv;

final static String TWITTER_API_KEY = "api_key";
final static String TWITTER_API_SECRET = 
"secret_key";

@Override
protected ArrayList<TwitterTweet> doInBackground(Object... params) {
    ArrayList<TwitterTweet> twitterTweets = null;
    callerActivity = (ListActivity) params[1];
    if (params.length > 0) {
        TwitterAPI twitterAPI = new TwitterAPI(TWITTER_API_KEY, 
        TWITTER_API_SECRET);
        twitterTweets = twitterAPI.getTwitterTweets(params[0].toString());
        if (twitterTweets.contains(positive)) {
            Toast.makeText(callerActivity, "The number of positive words are 
        ", duration)

        }

    }
    return twitterTweets;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final ArrayList<TwitterTweet> twitterTweets) {

    ArrayAdapter<TwitterTweet> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<TwitterTweet>
    (callerActivity,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, 
    twitterTweets);
    callerActivity.setListAdapter(adapter);
    lv = callerActivity.getListView();

}
```

Comment: Please be more specific on what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Shink  if the words which i have initialized exists in each tweet and when i click on the tweet it should give me a toast message that the tweet is positive or negative 
example : "best" , if the tweet says , the movie was best , and when i click on the tweet it should say , the tweet is positive 
"worst" the movie is worst , when i click on the tweet it should say , the tweet is negative  
so sir if you understood the query please suggest me how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Resgister a item click listener in your list view:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Using `position` you can access data related to clicked position.

Answer (score 0):

Use setOnItemClickListener() on your listView and inside onItemClick() method, you can try as below:

```
Iterator<TwitterTweet> it = twitterTweets.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    TwitterTweet obj = it.next();
    // Loop through positive or negative string arrays to check for words
}
```

or you can use foreach loop as below:

```
for (TwitterTweet obj : twitterTweets)
{
    // Loop through positive or negative string arrays to check for words
}
```